# How to connect my Java application to Cassandra running through docker?

Tags: java, docker, cassandra, database-connection

I have the following java code:

```
String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";  
String keyspace = "testkeyspace"; 
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(serverIP).build();  
Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);
```

which i am trying to use to check my connection to Cassandra.

I have Cassandra locally installed in my own machine, and connecting there is successful.
My maven project is using the following

> spring-data-cassandra
>   2.0.6.RELEASE

However, when i am trying to connect my java application to Cassandra run by docker (with my local cassandra stopped) i encounter the following error:

> All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:
>   [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))

I do not know if my IP is wrong, but on my docker CQLSH the following message is written whenever i open my CQLSH:

> Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042. 
>   [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4] Use HELP for help.

Please help, i must have missed something here. Thank you!

Comment: check your post because you have different ip's: 172 and 127... and it's pretty confusing

Comment: Did you expose the port of the Cassandra Docker container? `docker run -p [host_port]:[cassandra_port]` ?

Comment: Sorry. It is actually 127. :p I am experimenting different IP that is why.. but generally its 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Mornor what should i write on the [host_port]:[cassandra_port] ? Should i write, docker run -p 8080:8080

Comment: I don't know which port Cassandra uses by default. From your post, it seems tp be `:9042`. So the Docker command should ne something like: `docker run -p 10080:9042 cassandra:latest`. You will then be able to access Cassandra on `localhost:10080`

Comment: Could you post `docker run` command you use to launch cassandra?

Comment: @Mornor hey!! it worked like magic xD I used 9042:9042 Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @mulg0r docker run -p 9042:9042 cassandra:latest ====> this worked xDDD

Comment: Glad it worked :) I added an answer to the question instead of comments for others to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add my answer here, as it's been accepted as a comment in order to help others with the same issue.

You should expose your Cassandra Docker container port to localhost with:

`docker run -p 9042:9042 cassandra:latest`

Cassandra should now be accessible on `localhost:9042`